# Error ValueError: day is out of range for month

Tags: python

I was looking at a sample table of student information and wanted to see what days were the most popular for students to enroll on a course.  The script worked fine the first day I ran it and I left it.  A few days later I returned to take another look at it but started getting the ValueError message.

> Why did it stop working? No new information was added to the dataset
> since it worked the first time.  The code now fails at
> **df["EnrolmentDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df.EnrolmentDate)**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns
colors = sns.cubehelix_palette(28, rot=-0.4)

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

#print(df.dtypes)

# To change the format of the data type from object to datetime.  Has to be run at start of script or the format returns to object.
#df['Enrolment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Enrolment Date'])

print(df.EnrolmentDate.str.slice(0, 10))

df["EnrolmentDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df.EnrolmentDate)
print(df.head())
print(df.dtypes)
#Tells us what day of the week the enrolment date was.  Can also use .dayofyear. Google Pandas API Reference, search for .dt., datetime properties
print(df.EnrolmentDate.dt.weekday_name)

#Shows the latest or greatest enrolment date
print(df.EnrolmentDate.max())

print(df.EnrolmentDate.min())

print(df.EnrolmentDate.max()-df.EnrolmentDate.min())

df["EnrolmentDay"] =  df.EnrolmentDate.dt.weekday_name
print(df.head())

print(df.EnrolmentDay.value_counts())
print(df.EnrolmentDay.value_counts().plot())

#print(df.Day.value_counts().sort_index())

#df.EnrolmentDay.value_counts().sort_index().plot()
# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('Day') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('No. of Enrolments') 

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please add data.csv  file content with a minimum of five records.?

Comment: It is likely to be a problem of day vs month first in the date format. Pandas tries to identify it from the first records, but it sometimes assumes the wrong order and later fails. You should make sure of it and pass it as a parameter to `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: Why did it run ok the first time but stop a few days later?

Comment: As @SergeBallesta mentioned it looks like a day vs month problem. You could overcome this with a per-column 'styler'. Just check the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Comment: I figured it out.  It was indeed a day vs month problem as suggested.  I was using a master file of the data instead of the one I had reconfigured the dates in.  Thanks for the help.  Monday morning brain has not kicked in yet.